# re-direct component onClick with NavLink

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using Material Table with React Hooks my desire is to re-direct onClick. Currently the onClick is non-responsive.

**Material Table Component**

```
actions={[
        {
          onClick: (items) => {
           /*
             I want to re-direct to another route("/editperson") + 
             component(EditPerson.tsx) and send it props from this component
           */
          }
        }
      ]}
```

**NavigateToEditPerson.tsx**

```
function NavigateToEditPerson() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavLink to={{ pathname: "/editPerson" }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the useHistory hook and call history.push(`/editPerson/${item.name}`) for example to route to that link. If you use react router, you can access the params with useParams, if you declared that in the route definition.

But since this is neither an issue nor has something fundemental to do with the table itself, I would recommend to close this issue. This should be ask in the Forum or on stack overflow. Thank you.